# OpenGL nvoglv64.dll access violation

Tags: c++, opengl

I am doing a 4 stage rendering pipeline using OpenGL. After I changed a few things (and updated the drivers) the code stopped working. The error is caused by stage 4 in the following function:

```
    // STAGE 1 (Solid Render) ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        if (subSceneDebugFlag) { std::cout << "         Stage 1..." << std::endl; }

        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, this->subSceneFBO1);
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glUseProgram(this->subSceneShaderArray[0]);

            glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->textureAsset->colorMapID);
            glUniform1i(this->stage1ColorMapLocation, 0);

            glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->textureAsset->normalMapID);
            glUniform1i(this->stage1NormalMapLocation, 1);

            glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->textureAsset->specularMapID);
            glUniform1i(this->stage1SpecularMapLocation, 2);

            glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE3);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->textureAsset->lightMapID);
            glUniform1i(this->stage1LightMapLocation, 3);

        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
        glDisable(GL_BLEND);

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(4);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(5);

        // Binding SSBO
            glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, this->objectSSBO);
            glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 1, this->objectSSBO);

        // Binding VBO
                glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER); // Make sure the buffer is unmapped

            glBindVertexArray(this->objectVAO);
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->objectVBO);
            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexIndex);

        glDisableVertexAttribArray(5);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(4);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(3);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);

    // STAGE 2 (Solid Shading) ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        if (subSceneDebugFlag) { std::cout << "         Stage 2..." << std::endl; }

        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, this->subSceneFBO2);
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glUseProgram(this->subSceneShaderArray[1]);

            glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->stage1ColorMapID);
            glUniform1i(this->stage2ColorMapLocation, 0);

            glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->stage1NormalMapID);
            glUniform1i(this->stage2NormalMapLocation, 1);

            glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->stage1SpecularMapID);
            glUniform1i(this->stage2SpecularMapLocation, 2);

            glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE3);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->stage1LightMapID);
            glUniform1i(this->stage2LightMapLocation, 3);

            glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE4);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->stage1DepthMapID);
            glUniform1i(this->stage2DepthMapLocation, 4);

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

        glBindVertexArray(this->subSceneVAO);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->subSceneVBO);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

    // STAGE 3 (Alpha Shading) ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////          
        if (subSceneDebugFlag) { std::cout << "         Stage 3..." << std::endl; }

        glUseProgram(this->subSceneShaderArray[2]);

            glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->textureAsset->colorMapID);
            glUniform1i(this->stage3ColorMapLocation, 0);

            glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->textureAsset->normalMapID);
            glUniform1i(this->stage3NormalMapLocation, 1);

            glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->textureAsset->specularMapID);
            glUniform1i(this->stage3SpecularMapLocation, 2);

            glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE3);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->textureAsset->lightMapID);
            glUniform1i(this->stage3LightMapLocation, 3);

        glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);
        glEnable(GL_BLEND);

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(4);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(5);

        // Binding SSBO
            glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, this->objectSSBO);
            glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 1, this->objectSSBO);

        // Binding VBO
            glBindVertexArray(this->objectVAO);
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->objectVBO);
            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexIndex);

        glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);

        glDisableVertexAttribArray(5);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(4);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(3);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);

// STAGE 4 (Draw To Buffer) ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////      
    if (subSceneDebugFlag) { std::cout << "         Stage 4..." << std::endl; }

        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, this->subSceneFBO4);

        glUseProgram(this->subSceneShaderArray[3]);

            glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->stage2ColorMapID);
            glUniform1i(this->stage4ColorMapLocation, 0);

            glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->stage1ControlMapID);
            glUniform1i(this->stage4ControlMapLocation, 1);

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

        glBindVertexArray(this->subSceneVAO);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->subSceneVBO);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
```

If I comment out stage 4, there is no error. If I comment out stage 2, stage 4 works properly. In fact, I believe something in FBO2 and FBO4 causes the issue, the only thing shared between them is the VAO/VBO.

Google search did not provide any results. The problems in all cases were caused by either drivers, or bad pointers. As I mentioned, they both stages work when used separated so my object initialization is out of question.

Other reasons include wrong or missing attributes, which I don't think is the case here.

I would like to know what I'm missing.

Can using same VAO/VBO in two frame buffer objects be the issue?

EDIT: The latest drivers still have the issue.

Comment: Usually a driver access violation is caused by something not being bound (so the driver has a null deref bug), or by telling the driver to access invalid memory. Framebuffers have nothing to do with VAOs/VBOs, that is *not* the cause.

Comment: So what could be the issue if they work on their own, but fail when they operate together? If they operate together then clearly OpenGL is able to allocate everything properly.

Comment: Have you tried commenting out individual parts of stage 2 and individual parts of stage 4 to find out which parts don't like to work together?

Comment: I replaced the VAO/VBO in Stage 4 with another set, same exact size and layout. It doesn't crash now, but it doesn't render anything either. It makes no sense.

Comment: Is it possible that one or the other buffer is 0 so you are actually unbinding it? When no buffer is bound, several OpenGL functions require a pointer, instead of a buffer offset.

Comment: Yes, nothing is 0, and glCheckFramebuffer confirms that everything is okay.

Comment: If I disable stage 3 but enable stage 4, then it works too. I am really lost here. I cannot disable things any further, without not drawing anything.

Answer (score 1):

glEnableVertexAttribArray() is only meant to be called when creating the VAO. After that you should not touch that at all, binding the proper VAO will do that.

By enabling/disabling things I was altering the currently attached VAO, which caused issues down the line.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably caused by a broad range of things since it's a driver error. In my case, my error came from:

A glTexImage2D call which used the GL_RGBA instead of GL_RGB.  (my image didn't have an alpha channel so the driver was trying to access an extra bit of memory that was invalid)